# Consulta sobre formato de texto en TkInter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy aprendiendo el lenguaje Python y estoy practicando con TkInter. Ya terminé un programa y el intérprete me muestra el texto bien. No obstante, cuando lo ejecuto desde el terminal de Linux, me muestra el texto así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe a qué se debe? ¿Es algo propio del terminal, o hay alguna línea de código que tengo que añadir al programa para que me muestre el texto en el mismo formato que cuando lo ejecuto en el intérprete?

Adjunto el [código del programa](https://pastebin.com/3jN6vmxR) por si me falta algo ahí.

Desde ya agradezco las respuestas. Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Supongo que la fuente default de Tkinter entre Windows y Linux son distintas. Pero no se nada más, ya que no se nada de Linux. Por cierto, el código debe estar en la pregunta en forma de [ejemplo minimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), ya que si el link se cae por algún motivo, la pregunta se volverá inutil para futuros lectores.

Comment: No se me había ocurrido que podía tener que ver con las tipografías predeterminadas del SO. Ahora estuve probando cambiando tipografías por las predeterminadas de la distro y ocurre lo mismo. Me imagino que sería mejor consultar en los foros de la distro que estoy usando. Y bueno, sobre el pastebin, en realidad sucede con cualquier programa en TkInter que escribo. Gracias igual por la sugerencia.